# Using Pandas and Sklearn.Neighbors

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, python-3.5, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to fit a KNN model on a dataframe, using Python 3.5/Pandas/Sklearn.neighbors. I've imported the data, split it into training and testing data and labels, but when I try to predict using it, I get the following error. I'm quite new to Pandas so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cross_validation
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
seeds = pd.read_csv('seeds.tsv',sep='\t',names=['Area','Perimeter','Compactness','Kern_len','Kern_width','Assymetry','Kern_groovlen','Species'])
data = seeds.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
labels = seeds.iloc[:,[7]]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(data,labels, test_size=0.4, random_state=1 )
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=30)
knn.fit(x_train,y_train)
knn.predict(x_test)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-2292e64e5ab8> in <module>()
----> 1 knn.predict(x_test)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\regression.py in predict(self, X)
    151 
    152         if weights is None:
--> 153             y_pred = np.mean(_y[neigh_ind], axis=1)
    154         else:
    155             y_pred = np.empty((X.shape[0], _y.shape[1]), dtype=np.float)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   2876 
   2877     return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
-> 2878                           out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
   2879 
   2880 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     66     if isinstance(ret, mu.ndarray):
     67         ret = um.true_divide(
---> 68                 ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
     69     elif hasattr(ret, 'dtype'):
     70         ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Your are using a regressor, so the labels must be numbers, not strings --- so you'll have to encode the latter, if that even makes sense... Are you sure you want a kNN regressor and not a kNN classifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the `KNeighborsClassifier` for this KNN. You are trying to predict the label `Species` for classification. The regressor in your code above is trying to train and predict continuously valued numerical variables, which is where your problem is being introduced.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
seeds = pd.read_csv('seeds.tsv',sep='\t',names=['Area','Perimeter','Compactness','Kern_len','Kern_width','Assymetry','Kern_groovlen','Species'])
data = seeds.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
labels = seeds.iloc[:,[7]]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(data,labels, test_size=0.4, random_state=1 )
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=30)
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_classification.html

Here is what the regressor would plot compared to the classifier (which you want to use).

[image: Regressor]

[image: Classifier]