# Finding similar entities using python

Tags: python, pandas, knn

I am trying to figure out a way to measure the similarity between objects, in this cases stores.
Lets say we have a list of 5 stores. And we have the following monthly metrics for each:

- Month - The month in question (Jan - Dez)
- TotalSales - The total sales amount
- NumCustomers - Number of customers who bought at the store
- AvgUnitPrice - The average price they paid per unit.

A sample of the dataset would look something like this:

```
Store   Month   TotalSales  NumCustomers    AvgUnitPrice
  1      Jan        100          10              5.00
  2      Jun        150          12              4.70
  3      Mar        200          20              4.95
  4      Apr        100          13              3.80
  5      Dec        300          25              4.36
```

I have store 6 with the same variables (TotalSales, NumCustomers & AvgUnitPrice).

How can I quantify how similar each store (1 - 5) is to store 6 in terms of the metrics above mentioned?

I have hypothesized two approaches just don't know yet how to implement them.

- Approach 1: Using a function that calculates a person correlation. Example output (store 1 - store 6 = 86%)
- Approach 2: Using a model that calculates distances eg KNN to figure out which stores are the 'closest'.

Would appreciate any guidance with this matter. Peace :)

Comment: One solution would be to use pandas dataframes to store your data (which you might by already using) and then use the [`pandas.DataFrame.corrwith()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) method for the approach 1 and then using some [`Sklearn.neighbours`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682124/using-pandas-and-sklearn-neighbors) methods for the approach 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple version would be a vector cosine similarity.  `sklearn` includes an implementation, so something like this (convert month to numeric values, then normalize features before computing similarity):

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import numpy as np

df_dict = {'Store': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'Month': {0: 'Jan', 1: 'Jun', 2: 'Mar', 3: 'Apr', 4: 'Dec'},
 'TotalSales': {0: 100, 1: 150, 2: 200, 3: 100, 4: 300},
 'NumCustomers': {0: 10, 1: 12, 2: 20, 3: 13, 4: 25},
 'AvgUnitPrice': {0: 5.0, 1: 4.7, 2: 4.95, 3: 3.8, 4: 4.36}}

d = {"Jan":1, "Feb":2, "Mar":3, "Apr":4, "May":5, "Jun":6, "Jul":7, "Aug":8, "Sep":9, "Oct":10, "Nov":11, "Dec":12}
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
# generate period month feature - nearby months more similar
df["Month"] = np.sin(df["Month"].map(d)/12*2*np.pi)
X = df.drop(columns="Store")
X = pd.DataFrame(sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(X, axis=0), columns=X.columns)

m_cos = cosine_similarity(X, X)

df_cos = pd.DataFrame(m_cos, columns=df["Store"], index=df["Store"])
```

output:

```
Store         1         2         3         4         5
Store
1      1.000000  0.847529  0.948407  0.939495  0.743462
2      0.847529  1.000000  0.759483  0.663606  0.938521
3      0.948407  0.759483  1.000000  0.982677  0.757679
4      0.939495  0.663606  0.982677  1.000000  0.630423
5      0.743462  0.938521  0.757679  0.630423  1.000000
```